# Custom abbreviation in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a question concerning the formatting of the bibliography output in my LaTeX file. I have an auxiliary `.bib` archive where I manage the bibliography. In one citation there are multiple authors so the output in the LaTeX PDF is something like [GHDDIMLTEM32]. I would like to know if it is possible to add some lines of code in the `@article{ }` aforementioned to produce an output like [CUSTOM]. Thank you very much for your time.

I am using the following code

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mybibliogrpahy}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you use bibtex (you named it in the title) or biblatex (you used the tag). Please clarify ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in the following link [https://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/blog/20171208-bibtex-custom-label.html](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Egautam/sj/blog/20171208-bibtex-custom-label.html)

"Now if you want to cite your entries with a custom label (e.g. A17 instead of the default Aut17), then provide the label you want in the label field. For example:"

```
@Article{     foo,
  label         = {A17},
  author        = {Author, A},
  title         = {Example entry},
  journal       = {ArXiv e-prints},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eprint        = {1707.03780},
  primaryclass  = {physics.flu-dyn},
  doi           = {10.1010/doi-that-will-become-a-hyperlink},
  url           = {http://your.custom.url},
  year          = 2017,
}
```